# Can typeof Array'instance return ’Array' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If a is an instance of `Array`. We know `typeof a` will returns `'object'`, but I want to make it return `'array'`, can I do this？

If I can then how do I do it
If not then why not?

Comment: Use `Array.isArray()` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't - an array *is* an object, plain and simple:

```js
const aRealArray = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(typeof aRealArray);
```

You *can* check if something is an array, however, by using `Array.isArray` or `instanceof`

```js
const aRealArray = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(Array.isArray(aRealArray));
console.log(aRealArray instanceof Array);
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(aRealArray));
```

Note that `Array.isArray` is the more reliable version (and as pointed out by [@MattBrowne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560114/matt-browne) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/97608441) below, it works across iframes). `instanceof` simply checks if `Array.prototype` is on a prototype chain.

Comment: Note that using `Array.isArray()` is the more reliable of the two methods suggested in this answer (works even across iframes).

Comment: Yes @MattBrowne - I just wanted to add in `instanceof` for prototypes. I'll add that information in my answer.

Comment: there's also `Object.prototype.toString.call(aRealArray)` which returns the string `"[object Array]"`

Comment: Yes @JaromandaX, I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Array's "isArray" method, which returns a boolean:

```
Array.isArray(a)
```

Comment: As a note, `Array.isArray()` requires a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray#Polyfill) if you're still using IE8.